# How to get rid of the space in between two divs?

Tags: html, css

I have to divs layouted as display: inline-block. Intentionally, I want these two divs (tileImage, title) to share the 300px width of the parent div (preview). Thus, I have set their width to 50%. For some reason the second div is moved to the next line.

Changing the width of `div` "title" to `48%` will move the div next to the `div` "titleImage". There you notice the space in between. Where does this space come from? How do I get rid of it?

Here is the JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SFDPe/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should float your elements to the left and right, instead. Then, make sure you set `height: auto;` and `overflow: auto;` to the parent container. This ensures that the `.parent` container actually overflows and grows automatically when elements are floated inside of it.

[JSfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SFDPe/6/)

```
.preview {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.title {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: olive;
    float: right;
}

.tileImage {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `display:inline-block` use, `float:left` for both divs.
http://jsfiddle.net/SFDPe/3/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look onto this article:

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Maybe you can use `float: left;` instead? Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SFDPe/7/):

```
.preview, .preview div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: and add float:left to #preview to restore the border there as well.